# How to send and receive data from one endpoint of an api to another endpoint of an api in flask framework?

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, frameworks

The following is my code, I am using python3

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,jsonify,request,abort
import pymysql
import json
import requests
app=Flask(__name__)
item = ()
connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",database="cloud" )
cursor = connection.cursor()
@app.route("/api/v1/add_user",methods=["POST"])
def add_user():
    user_name = request.get_json()['user_name']
    dataToSend = {'data':'sent_by_add_user_api'}
    requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/read_data', json=dataToSend)
    return jsonify(user_name)

@app.route("/api/v1/read_data",methods=["POST"])
def read_data():
    input_json = requests.get() 
    return jsonify(input_json)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.debug=True
    app.run(port=5000)

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I want the dictionary sent by add_user to available in read_data, I am not sure about the syntax of request.get and request.post. 
I am new to the flask framework, any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? I wish to do the same thing and also I don't know how to go about it. Any help would be awesome!